# How can I create a drawable image for a contact form

Tags: plugins, plugin-contact-form-7

I'm trying to create a new patient form and Im not sure the best way to create a section with an image of a body so that they can draw on it to indicate where on the body they hurt. It has been done on this site, https://elevatehealthfacilities.com/online-forms/, but I cannot figure out how to go about it. Is there a plugin or a way to make this in Divi?

Comment: note that you can't ask for recommendations here, do you know how to implement the drawing in static HTML/JS? Where is the code for your form?

Comment: The site you want to emulate appears to use WordPress; you could reach out to them and ask what plugin(s) they're using to achieve this goal.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.